# Error en return de funcion en C con array como parametro

Tags: array, c, funciones

tengo que hacer un ejercicio en C :

"Generar un subprograma que permita, dado un vector de 10 posiciones, obtener la suma de los elementos que están ubicados en las posiciones pares del mismo. Los valores del vector son reales (float). Guardar el resultado en un archivo mediante la instrucción fprintf()."

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

FILE *fd;

float sumar(float a[],int n);//prototipo de función

int main(){

    float array[10];
    float suma;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i <10;i++){
        printf("ingrese los valores del array: ");
        scanf("%f",&array[i]);
    }

    sumar(array,10);

    printf("%2f",suma);

    /*fd = fopen("archivo.txt", "w");  //el archivo se crea donde este ejecutando el programa

    if(fd == NULL){
        printf("El archivo no pudo crearse");

    }else{
        printf("El archivo, archivo.txt fue creado con exito");
    }

    fprintf(fd,"%.2f",suma);

    fclose(fd);

    */

    getch();
    return 0;

}

float sumar(float a[],int n){
    float suma;
    int i;


    for(i=0; i <10;i++){

        if( i %2 == 0){
                suma = a[i] + suma;

            }

        }
    return suma;
}
```

El retorno de la variable suma es 0.00 y no el valor de la suma de la cantidad valores del array y necesito corregir eso, por que no se donde esta la falla
( en el archivo que cree para probarlo es archivo.txt y puse 1234567891, por lo que la suma debería dar 10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1er error: No guardas el resultado en ningun sitio**

Dada la declaración de la función `sumar`:

```
float sumar(float a[],int n);
```

Se entiende que retorna en forma de `float` el resultado de la suma... sin embargo tu ignoras dicho resultado de forma deliberada:

```
sumar(array,10);
```

Luego es imposible que el resultado acabe de forma mágica en la variable `suma`. Te falta la asignación:

```
suma = sumar(array, 10);
```

**2º error: No inicializas las variables**

El caso es que una vez corrijas el punto anterior, puedes acabar descubriendo que el algoritmo te devuelve resultados extraños y eso pasa por no inicializar las variables:

```
float sumar(float a[],int n){
    float suma = 0.0; // Inicializamos suma

    for(int i=0; i <10;i++) // Reducimos la vida de i
    {
        if( i %2 == 0)
        {
            suma = a[i] + suma;
        }
    }
    return suma;
}

int main()
{

    float array[10];

    for(int i = 0; i <10;i++){ // Reducimos la vida de i
        printf("ingrese los valores del array: ");
        scanf("%f",&array[i]);
    }

    float suma = sumar(array,10); // Retrasamos la creacion de suma

    printf("%2f",suma);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, tuve que editar, ya que indique mal la consigna del ejercicio. las observaciones que me diste me ayudaron a corregir los errores, Muchas gracias de nuevo! @eferion